# Is folder uploading possible in PHP?

Tags: php, http

Is there any way to upload an entire folder using PHP?

Comment: … using PHP as the receiver of that folder over HTTP?

Comment: Poorly written question and shows a lack of understanding between PHP and browsers.

Comment: The question is perfectly straightforward and this question is being asked to solve the lack of understanding you downvoted this person for. I gave it an upvote to cancel your downvote.

Comment: Yikes, don't edit a question to completely change the title! Just ask a new question!

Comment: I rolled it back, since all of the answers are about uploading folders. If the original author wants to ask about CSS, he should ask a new question.

Comment: yea am realy sorry... some of the users are trying to downvote the post, i don't know why they behave like this. that is why tried to change the question. :(

am realy sorry for all the users which given the correct answers.
and thank you Zanoni, Kazar, Noctrine, Coding With Style,Gumbo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Its not a limitation of PHP, but a limitation of the browser itself. There is no way to select a folder for upload (and pass the data through).

You could however upload an archive, and then use php to unzip it.

Comment: I was looking for this answer.. I had a feeling, but just had to make sure. I'm using Jumploader Java applet to circumvent this issue, BTW - great little Java Applet that allows folder uploads, and minor editing functions such as rotating JPGs etc. for your ease of use. I absolutely love it, and the UI looks very modern - much better improvement compared to the old school file managers in Java or Flash.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a limitation of PHP, but of the browsers themselves. They don't allow you to select a "folder" to upload. You can only do a file; one file per input tag.

Your best bet is to zip a folder, upload it and use PHP to unzip it on the local file system.

or

You could use (Java Applet): http://jupload.biz/

or

(Flash) http://swfupload.org/

Comment: I suppose a partial solution would be SWFUpload, since it allows multiple file selection. Files are uploaded individually too, so the constraint on post max size is on a per-file basis.

Answer (score 0):

No, not only php, you would require an activex control (IE only) or java applet.

Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupload/, it is a java applet intended to allow multiple file/folder uploading.